# Python Email Selective Notification

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

I am new to python 3, and want to write a script that will notify me on my desktop only if I receive emails from specific senders. My target email client is Outlook (the email address is actually a hotmail address). Is there a way to do this that a newbie would be able to understand?

Comment: why not add filter in the outlook itself ?

Comment: @sahasrara62 I've not been able to find such a setting anywhere in Outlook. I also think that I have something to learn from this, so it probably wouldn't be a bad idea to learn how to do it anyway.

Comment: [this may help you](https://www.howtogeek.com/239131/how-to-get-outlook-notifications-for-important-emails-only/)

Comment: I have not been able to find that particular option, even in the rules I can set, that tutorial was for a previous version of Outlook, and some of those options aren't visible to me

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this question has anything at all to do with Python. You can make a few modifications in Outlook, that notifies you when you receive an email from a specific user, or group of specific users.

Create a Rule for a Specific Person

To set up a custom alerting rule for a specific person, open Outlook and then find an email from someone for whom you want an alert. Right-click the email and select Rules > Create Rule.

[image: The "Create Rule" option in the context menu.]

Alternatively, select the email, and on the Home tab of the ribbon, click Rules > Create Rule.

[image: The "Create Rule" option in the ribbon menu.]

Switch on the checkbox next to the sender’s name and then choose “Display In The New Item Alert Window” and/or “Play A Selected Sound.”

[image: The "Create Rule" window with the alert options highlighted.]

If you choose “Play A Selected Sound,” then you’ll have to choose a sound file to play. Most people don’t keep a selection of .wav files to hand, so navigate to C:\Windows\Media (or /System/Library/Sounds/ if you’re using Outlook on a Mac) and choose the sound you want. You can use the play button in the “Create Rule” window to hear the sound before you confirm your choice.

[image: The "Create Rule" window with the play button highlighted.]

Click “OK” in the Create Rule window, and your rule is set. From now on, you’ll be alerted whenever you receive a message from that email address.

See the link below for all relevant info.

https://www.howtogeek.com/673562/how-to-get-notifications-for-only-the-emails-you-care-about-in-microsoft-outlook/